# Guessing recursion in rational functions

Tags: recursion, difference-equations

[image]I want to know if there is a package in Mathematica that can give back some recursion given a list of polynomial in $f_{n}(h)$. For example I know there exists package RISC guess that where I give some list of rational numbers it can give me the recursion it satisfies. 
My list is as follows 
[1,0,-2,$-h^2+3$,$5h^2+1$,$-5h^2-11$,$-35h^2+15$,$-21h^4+140h^2+13$,$189h^4-84h^2-77$]
I want a recursion of the from 
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{N}a_{k}(h)[n]f(n+k) =0  $$

where $a_{k}(h)[n]$ is a polynomial in $n$ over the rational field $Q(h)$.

An example done in Guess package is as follows [image]

[{1,1},{2,0},{3,-2},
{4,-h^2+3},{5,5*h^2+1},{5,5*h^2+1},{6,-5*h^2-11},{7,-35*h^2+15},{8,-21*h^4+140*h^2+13},{9,189*h^4-84*h^2-77},{10,-462*h^4-840*h^2+86},{11,-1848*h^4+2640*h^2+144},{12,-1485*h^6+15015*h^4-495*h^2-595},{13,19305*h^6-27027*h^4-16445*h^2+495},{14,-78507*h^6-102102*h^4+41041*h^2+1520},{15,-173745*h^6+636636*h^4+11375*h^2-4810},{16,-225225*h^8+2922920*h^6-816816*h^4-282100*h^2+2485},{17,3828825*h^8-9432280*h^6-4084080*h^4+559300*h^2+15675},{18,-22141548*h^8-15801500*h^6+19399380*h^4+474300*h^2-39560},{19,-15796638*h^8+218196836*h^6-15872220*h^4-4399260*h^2+6290},{20,-59520825*h^10+897498459*h^8-554268000*h^6-128741340*h^4+6807225*h^2+159105},{21,1249937325*h^10-4414328919*h^8-1127011600*h^6+476030940*h^4+11062275*h^2-324805},{22,-9445293585*h^10-903687785*h^8+10988363100*h^6-171609900*h^4-63677075*h^2-87075},{23,6418990305*h^10+101767530865*h^8-21565644100*h^6-3397876020*h^4+73363675*h^2+1592843}]

Comment: It would be useful to have an example that can be cut and pasted.

Comment: I copy paste an example if it helps. It from RISC GUESS pacakge where they can do it for rational numbers but for me it's polynomials.

Comment: I cannot cut and paste an image...

Comment: I see so which format is good for you ? I can send you a pdf file ?

Comment: Just put plain ascii text, in Mathematica input form, into the actual question. So one "row" could be the Mathematica list `{10,-462*h^4-840*h^2+86}` for example.

Comment: I put the list at the end of the question. Hope it works.

Comment: @GGT there is such a function, namely `FindSequenceFunction`, but it doesn't produce a recurrence for your data.

Comment: @GGT for coefficients at $h^0$, $h^2$, $h^4$ it does produce some different recurrences.

Comment: Oh that's great can you please give me that recurrence. And how you did it. I can make the recurrence of my data from the recurrence you have. Thanks again

Comment: Thanks for the example. Playing with it a bit I do not think there is much hope for a "nice" result. Specifically I take all second elements, drop the first few, then partition with an offset of 1 and compute a null space. One can fashion the desired a_k(n) from that. But there do not seem to be any "nice" nulls involving say partitioning in groupd fo 6 or less.

Comment: Thanks for trying. So you mean you have tried to find an recursion in case when $N=5$? Also you only tried the recursion for the even elements in the list ?

Comment: I tried for n=5 and I think also n=8 or so. I used all elements except the first few (the "initial values') since i suspected they might only confuse the method. Any solution to the full set of values would also work on the more restricted set i used, but not necessarily vice versa.

Comment: Yeah, sure you are right. There is also no recursion for n=8? Did you use any special package or command? If you have some work can you share please.

Comment: I think I made a silly mistake by saying I want $a_{k}(h)$ what I want is $a_{k}(h)[n]$. Which is a polynomial in $n$ over the field $\mathbb{Q}(h)$. As Andrew mentions the recursion for the constant or coefficients of $h^2$ that involves polynomial in $n$.

Comment: Call that input `seq` (using curly braces rather than square brackets so it is in proper Wolfram Language notation). What I did is quite simple. `In[728]:= mat = Partition[seq[[4 ;;, 2]], 8, 1];
NullSpace[mat]

Out[729]= {}`. Empty null space means no linear recurrence up to order 8 with polynomial coefficients (which implies none with rational function coeffs).

Comment: What i wrote above of course does not rule out linear recurrences with coefficients that depend on `n`. That`s a whole different bowl of soup.

Answer (score 1):

```
pollist = {{1, 1}, {2, 0}, {3, -2}, {4, -h^2 + 3}, {5, 5*h^2 + 1}, {5,
     5*h^2 + 1}, {6, -5*h^2 - 11}, {7, -35*h^2 + 15}, {8, -21*h^4 + 
     140*h^2 + 13}, {9, 
    189*h^4 - 84*h^2 - 77}, {10, -462*h^4 - 840*h^2 + 
     86}, {11, -1848*h^4 + 2640*h^2 + 144}, {12, -1485*h^6 + 
     15015*h^4 - 495*h^2 - 595}, {13, 
    19305*h^6 - 27027*h^4 - 16445*h^2 + 495}, {14, -78507*h^6 - 
     102102*h^4 + 41041*h^2 + 1520}, {15, -173745*h^6 + 636636*h^4 + 
     11375*h^2 - 4810}, {16, -225225*h^8 + 2922920*h^6 - 816816*h^4 - 
     282100*h^2 + 2485}, {17, 
    3828825*h^8 - 9432280*h^6 - 4084080*h^4 + 559300*h^2 + 
     15675}, {18, -22141548*h^8 - 15801500*h^6 + 19399380*h^4 + 
     474300*h^2 - 39560}, {19, -15796638*h^8 + 218196836*h^6 - 
     15872220*h^4 - 4399260*h^2 + 6290}, {20, -59520825*h^10 + 
     897498459*h^8 - 554268000*h^6 - 128741340*h^4 + 6807225*h^2 + 
     159105}, {21, 
    1249937325*h^10 - 4414328919*h^8 - 1127011600*h^6 + 
     476030940*h^4 + 11062275*h^2 - 324805}, {22, -9445293585*h^10 - 
     903687785*h^8 + 10988363100*h^6 - 171609900*h^4 - 63677075*h^2 - 
     87075}, {23, 
    6418990305*h^10 + 101767530865*h^8 - 21565644100*h^6 - 
     3397876020*h^4 + 73363675*h^2 + 1592843}}[[All, 2]];
```

For free coefficients

```
coef0[n_] = FindSequenceFunction[Coefficient[#, h, 0] & /@ pollist, n]
```

gives

> DifferenceRoot[{[FormalY],[FormalN]}[Function]{([FormalN]+4) (2936
>   [FormalN]^2-13255 [FormalN]+13103) [FormalY]([FormalN]+3)+(11818
>   [FormalN]^3-39180 [FormalN]^2+12312 [FormalN]+47530)
>   [FormalY]([FormalN]+1)+(4441 [FormalN]^3-7769 [FormalN]^2-21002
>   [FormalN]+47530) [FormalY]([FormalN]+2)-5 ([FormalN]-5) [FormalN]
>   (1431 [FormalN]-1199)
>   [FormalY]([FormalN])==0,[FormalY](1)==1,[FormalY](2)==0,[FormalY](3)==-2}][n]

Check:

```
Table[coef0[k], {k, 1, 24}]
```

> {1,0,-2,3,1,1,-11,15,13,-77,86,144,-595,495,1520,-4810,2485,15675,-39560,6290,159105,-324805,-87075,1592843}

For the coefficients at $h^2$

```
coef2[n_] = FindSequenceFunction[Coefficient[#, h, 2] & /@ pollist, n]
```

> DifferenceRoot[{[FormalY],[FormalN]}[Function]{(550
>   [FormalN]^3-2640 [FormalN]^2+1220 [FormalN]+1110)
>   [FormalY]([FormalN]+1)+(237 [FormalN]^3-1527 [FormalN]^2+2442
>   [FormalN]-672) [FormalY]([FormalN]+2)+25 ([FormalN]-5) [FormalN]
>   (17 [FormalN]-5) [FormalY]([FormalN])+([FormalN]-2) ([FormalN]-1)
>   (76 [FormalN]-297)
>   [FormalY]([FormalN]+3)==0,[FormalY](1)==0,[FormalY](2)==0,[FormalY](3)==0,[FormalY](4)==-1,[FormalY](5)==5}][n]

etc.

BTW recurrences becomes simpler if to begin from the third line:

```
coef0[n_] = FindSequenceFunction[Coefficient[#, h, 0] & /@ pollist[[3 ;;]], n]
```

> DifferenceRoot[{[FormalY],[FormalN]}[Function]{(5 [FormalN]+10)
>   [FormalY]([FormalN])+(2 [FormalN]+7)
>   [FormalY]([FormalN]+1)+([FormalN]+5)
>   [FormalY]([FormalN]+2)==0,[FormalY](1)==-2,[FormalY](2)==3,[FormalY](3)==1,[FormalY](4)==1,[FormalY](5)==-11}][n]

Comment: Thanks for that. As I understand you gave the recursion for the constant term of the polynomials. What is Formal[Y], Formal[N] denotes? Is it possible to give a recursion for a bivariate table? The entry of the table would be $(d,coeff[f_d,h,2g])$. $f_d$ denote the $d-th$ polynomial in the list.

Comment: Yes, for the coefficients of $h^2$ too, changed the answer. As for `Formal[Y] `, `Formal[N]`  it's mathematica's symbols  introduced to not use `y`, `n` because those variables can be defined already.

Comment: you mean you have a different recursion for coefficients of $h^2$ ?

Comment: To make sure the above recursion for the constant coefficient read as follows $ (5n+10)*y(n)+(2n+7)*y(n+1)+(2n+5)*y(n+2)=0$.

Comment: @GGT yes, for different coefficients recursions are different.